# Regex to validate if string is a variable

Tags: php, regex

I'm currently working on a small framework type of project. In this project a `eval()` is needed. This eval string is not user-submitted, but i would still like to validate that the string is a (contains a) variable.

The types of variable could be both normal variables, class properties and superglobal variables. I'm new to regex so I would appreciate any help.

Just to clarify: the string would be this as an example contain something like this `'$_GET["something"]'`.

Comment: The *strict* definition of regexes is definitely not capable of validating whether a string is valid PHP, JavaScript, etc. PHP has some extensions, and likely it is possible. But programming languages are validated/pared using a *contex-free grammar*; like [this one](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_language_parser.y) for PHP.

Comment: Check out PHP_Parser in PEAR...  https://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Parser

Comment: Note that `$_GET["something"]` is not "eval-safe", for example, `$_GET["${\`format c:\`}"]`.

Comment: "*In this project a `eval()` is needed.*" – I'd take some time to seriously reconsider its necessity. Is `eval()` really (*really*, **really**, ***really***) needed? Sharing more about the problem being "solved" by `eval()` might lead to more suitable alternatives.

Comment: Indeed, mind all kinds of side-effects, and eval is one of the *easy* ways to hack into a webserver server. Of course one needs to find a way to inect in `eval`, but in many cases, that's not *undoable*. A lot of scripting languages seem to regret the `eval`. It is easy to do a call to the interpreter; but it is opening the box of pandora.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
(\$[a-zA-Z_]\w*(\[(["'])\w+\3\])?|\$\{\w+\})
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uI3yI6/7)

**Note:** It is better to use some libraries like [this](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_language_parser.y) and [this](https://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Parser) than using a regex solution. (From the discussions)

Comment: I assume the  `something` is a variable name, where variable names can't contain `]` for instance?

Comment: This "validates" e.g. `$foo[system("rm -rf /")]`. I don't think it would be safe to eval this.

Comment: And according to this `'$foo'` is a variable too.

Comment: @karthikmanchala: it's between single quotes, so it's a string with the dollar sign.

Comment: `system("rm -rf /"); // $foo` also matches this regex ([demo](https://eval.in/private/90531d4f89b34a)) — you might want some [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

Comment: ASCII 228 characters may be accepted. Something like that: `$täyte` 
See: [PHP variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: That's why it is in general a bad idea to do programming language processing yourself. Most of the concepts look easy, but in fact such languages are very complicated with all kinds of exceptions. Therefore one better uses a library.

Comment: @emartinelli  [`$☁❄☃☀☂`](https://eval.in/private/42e57792f85e2d) is also perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*(?:\[["']\w+["']\])?
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/cR8cS3/4)

ps.: (Extended) ASCII 228 is accepted in PHP

Reference: [php variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)

Comment: I'm not sure about the `\D`. This will match a new line or space character as well. The funny thing is that the regex is in the reference you point at: `\$[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*`. But now the challenge remains how you are going to filter on comments, strings, etc.

Comment: I edited. But filter on comments, strings, etc. will be a problem.